# My answer got edited without attribution

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits

Usually when a question or answer gets edited by somebody other than the person who wrote it, it says under the question who edited it. My answer at [Question about the solution to Unexpected hanging paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352370/question-about-the-solution-to-unexpected-hanging-paradox/1857771#1857771) is not the way I wrote it and it but it doesn't even say it was edited. I know it's illegal for somebody to copy something somebody else wrote and make it look like you thought of it by yourself, so I assume it's also illegal for somebody to make it look like somebody else wrote something they wrote.

Comment: What are the differences? How can you verify that you're not misremembering?

Comment: No, it's not illegal

Comment: the [timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1857771/timeline) doesn't show any revisions. Maybe a moderator removed stuff that was not appropriate as they can redact posts. Not sure if they always leave a comment for the OP though.

Comment: I still don't like people making it look like I wrote something I didn't write. It's possible that it was edited from my account by somebody in my house because it's a shared computer or my account got hacked.

Comment: The only way an edit won't leave revision, when done by same user, is when done within 5 minutes, aka grace period. You can't blame Stack Exchange if you leave your account open without logging out.

Comment: @rene Redacting a revision still leaves a trace. You basically see an "empty" revision in the list once that happens.

Comment: @adam do you have a sample for us to see?

Comment: @PatrickHofman http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279607/revisions. There are some potential variations in display here (in particular, tag-only revisions can behave a bit weirdly), but point is that any changes, especially ones that hard-delete something, leave a trace.

Comment: Okay. Nice to see how it looks like. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

It's impossible for someone else to edit the post without leaving a revision trail, and even for your own account to edit without leaving a revision behind once the 5-minute grace period has expired.

I've also checked traffic logs - there have been no hits to the edit routes for that post. The best I can tell you here is that you misremember what you wrote, sorry.

Comment: I definitely remember writing an answer different from the way it appears now. I remember what I wrote well enough that the way it appears now might be just a snippet of what I originally wrote. How can I remember something that didn't happen? Although I have no memory of it, it's slightly possible that I edited the answer later to the way it appears now then forgot about it entirely.